# String returning a float with one decimal place

Tags: java, format, decimal, decimalformat

I'm trying to format my decimal to show only one decimal place. In my testprogram I set gpa to 3.5454 and it is returning to me the value 3.5454. How do I format it to show 3.5. I tried the code below and it doesn't work. I also tried it in my setGpa method and still no luck

```
/**
 * This method return the student's gpa
 * @return This student's gpa
 */
public float getGpa(){
NumberFormat formatter= new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
formatter.format(gpa);
return gpa;
}
```

Solved! - I just needed to cast type it (float) ((int)(gpa*10) / 10)

Comment: Put in a _bit_ of effort for homework.  Look at some of the related questions on the right.

Comment: Do you want this to return a `float` (in other words, you want it rounded)?  Or to return a `String` (in other words, you want it formatted)?

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the float again. Maybe you instead wanted to

- round the float instead of format it
- return the `String` from `formatter.format(gpa)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try following solution

```
public static String getGpa(){
    NumberFormat formatter= new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
    String format = formatter.format(gpa);
    return format;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved! - I just needed to cast type it `(float) ((int)(gpa*10) / 10)`